# How to make report in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, date-time, reports

I am trying to make Report of Time registration part in SharePoint 2013. And I try to use Access View but SP 2013 doesn't have Access view or I didn't find out it. If you have any advice or suggestion share with me. I don't have any idea to start it.